# Google Maps Nearby Places

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Do anyone have Idea how can i pass multiple type of `types` in google maps pnearby place search

```
var map;
var infowindow;

function initMap() {
  var pyrmont = {lat: -33.867, lng: 151.195};

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 15
  });

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch({
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 500,
    types: ['store']
  }, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}
```

I tried to write types in many syntax as below but its Showing wrong places.

> ```
> types: 'bank|bar|airport'
> types: ['bank','bar']
> types: ['bank'|'bar']
> ```

do anyone have better solution i will appreciate.

Comment: What do you mean by "Showing wrong places"? Per the documentation, the first syntax you're using should be correct.

Comment: YES i agree So that i also think the same but when i use the 1st syntax it show me hotels also  and the Aquarium but no bank so i increased the radius to get better results but its dont show any Bank

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the required attribute `query`. This gives a keyword for the API to search on like the business name. The types provides additional filters to provide what it perceives to be the most relevant information to your request.

> This method takes a request with the following fields:

- query (required) The text string on which to search, for example:
  "restaurant". The Places service will return candidate matches based
  on this string and order the results based on their perceived
  relevance.
- types — An array containing one or more of the supported types listed in the Google Places API: Supported Place Types list. The service will return
  results that match any of the specified types.

```js
var map;
var infowindow;

function initMap() {
  var timesSquare = {
    lat: 40.759011,
    lng: -73.984472
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: timesSquare,
    zoom: 18
  });

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch({
    location: timesSquare,
    radius: 50,
    query: 'new york',
    types: ['bank'|'bar']
  }, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    console.log(results);
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initMap&libraries=places" async defer>
</script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: How can we change the types, for example i need (school, college, etc) to display. I tried to change like this, (types: ['colleges'|'school']) . how to get this data

Comment: Here are the supported types https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types